# Why this, highlighted, code won't work in React instead of useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

I was told not to use if statement in place of React.useEffect() cause it would result in an endless loop. Now, that it's no longer an endless loop why this does not work?

```
var counter = 0;

export default function App() {

  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn]= React.useState(false);

  if((localStorage.getItem('loginStatus')==='Logged In') && counter===0) {
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
    counter++;
  }
}
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" about your code?  At a glance, trying to track information in a global variable is probably a bad idea.  What is `counter` meant to do and why isn't it tracked in state?

Comment: I could not use setIsLoggedIn to reinitialize the state to true

Comment: if the counter variable was not there the setIsLoggedIn reinitializes the state to true. Now, because the state has been reinitialized the function component runs again and so does the if statement which in turn changes the state again to true and so the component renders again and again and again. To solve this I used the counter variable and incremented it to ensure that the if statement runs only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you're using the `setIsLoggedIn` method while the hooks aren't fully initialized yet.
Instead you have to replace your hook initialization to the following:

```js
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = React.useState((localStorage.getItem('loginStatus')==='Logged In') && counter===0);
```